# Operation timed out and Connection reset by peer - 400 concurrent accesses to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, tomcat, concurrency

**Some background**

I am working on project where we have a obsolete very simple bookshop web application from 1999 written in Java EE 1.4. However, the purpose is to modernize it in order to run it in cloud environment like Amazon AWS. We decided that we will rewrite it from start using Spring framework, Hibernate and c3p0 for connection pooling.

Beside web application we also got a stress tool for web application called RBE (Remote Browser Emulator). You simply tell RBE how many users do you want and he create one thread for each user. Each thread is randomly generating url and it is doing so as long as user browse the page (we defined that user browse site for 180 seconds). After that, it shuts down a thread, and that's. For each request it takes HTML page source, parse out jsessionid and then go on next url.

**The problem**

When I run RBE for 400 users (that is 400 requests per second), I quickly get the following exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:382)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:241)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:228)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:431)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:527)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:158)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:388)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:523)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:227)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:300)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:317)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:970)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:911)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:836)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1172)
    at rbe.EB.getHTML(EB.java:423)
    at rbe.EB.run(EB.java:324)
```

After a while, when RBEs try to browse other sub pages I get:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:382)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:241)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:228)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:431)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:527)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:158)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:388)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:523)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:227)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:300)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:317)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:970)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:911)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:836)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1172)
    at rbe.EB.getHTML(EB.java:423)
    at rbe.EB.run(EB.java:324)
```

The code at `EB.java:423)` (where the exception occur) is:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream() ) );
```

My `my.cnf` configuration:

```
[mysqld]
log=/var/log/mysqld.log
max_connections = 200
log-slow-queries = /var/log/mysqld_slow_queries.log
log-error = /usr/local/mysql/data/mysql-error.log
back-log = 200 
key_buffer_size=16M
max_allowed_packet=100M
interactive_timeout=30
wait_timeout=30
```

Tomcat relevant settings in `server.xml`:

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="500" />
```

I also did a test and served static html files with 2 seconds delay and did not do any iteraction with database. I did this test to see if Tomcat can't handle 400 concurrent requests. Tomcat passed this test successfully.

What is the bottleneck for 400 concurrent accesses to mysql? It's this too much for MySQL?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the exception traces you're showing are from the RBE load-testing client you're using to hammer away on your server stack. `Connection reset by peer` is an error condition that hints your server abandoned the connection at the TCP level in your HTTP/TCP/IP stack.  Do your server logs (in particular your connection pooling logs and HTTP server logs) show any evidence of resource exhaustion?

Comment: Usually, people doing load testing ramp up the load. Start with 10 or 20 virtual users, and add them 10 or 20 at a time until you find the first breaking point. Monitor stuff like simultaneous HTTP connections, machine load averages, and simultaneous MySQL connections as you crank things up.   Somebody else pointed out that 400 virtual users is an extremely large number. YAGNI

Answer (score 0):

Your my.cnf states that max_connections = 200. That might be a problem.

400 Requests is btw. a lot.

Comment: I tried to set max_connections=1000 but no difference. It seems like that Tomcat can't handle so many request or MySQL. I read somewhere that Tomcat can cause troubles because it can handle so many requests, and that Tomcat cancel requests to MySQL. Can somebody that know things in more details explain where's the problem?